# Is there any more succinct way to stub values in C# unit tests?

Tags: c#, mocking, nunit, moq

Coming from a Kotlin/Groovy/Spock background, I found it very straightforward to stub a value for specific arguments:

```
something.someMethod(1) >> "Stubbed Return Value"
```

Entering the C# / Moq world and needing to do this frequently for tests, I seem to be stuck with comparatively verbose code like:

```
somethingMock.Setup(x => x.SomeMethod(It.Is<int>(x => x == 1))).Returns("Stubbed Return value");
```

This is quite unwieldy.

Is there a better / more succinct way I'm missing for doing this in C#?

Comment: In some cases I find it easier/simpler to just create a custom class than mess around with the sometimes arcane syntax for Mocking frameworks.

Comment: @JonasH You mean like a "hardcoded Mock"? i.e. a class, that implements the interface in question and just "behaves" as the test needs it to?

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods exactly, not saying it is *always* the best way to do it. But in *some* cases I would certainly say it results in simpler and easier to understand tests.

Comment: @JonasH I am not disagreeing :) I would also say that there are mocking frameworks with a (subjectively) better API than Moq, closer to what OP describes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`It.Is<int>(x => x == 1)` can be written as just `1`. `It.Is` is useful once you want to perform expressions, but for literal values you don't need it. Just be careful when starting to compare with reference types instead of value types.

An example of where you could use `It.Is`:

```cs
somethingMock
    //I'm only interested in the Id of the instance
    .Setup(x => x.SomeMethod(It.Is<Person>(x => x.Id == 1)))
    .Returns("Stubbed Return value");
```

Comment: Thanks - hadn't realized it was that simple!